# Can an adjective come after a verb?

Tags: verbs, adjectives, word-order

I was trying to say "I write slow".

I figured it would be:

> おそい（が）かく。

But a native speaker didn't understand me and said it was:

> かくのがおそい。

Now I understand how の after a verb makes it a noun, but I always thought the verb had to be last. Why would you need to make it a noun if its the only acting verb?  Is there a reason why the way I said the sentence is wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In Japanese, the verb (or adjective) has to be at the end of the clause, so it can very well be in the middle of a sentence.

> おそい（が）かく

Is wrong because it doesn't make any sense. In this case, が would mean "but".

Even if you wrote:

> おそいかく

It would be wrong because you cannot qualify a verb (here かく) with an adjective (here おそい), it would literally mean "slow write".

In:

> かくのがおそい

You first nominalize the verb かく with の as you already know it makes it act like a noun. And then you qualify this nominal group with が/はおそい.

Comment: And the full idea is basically "(my) writing is slow", so you can make an English version where the verb becomes a noun too.

Comment: Yes, feel free to edit my answer if you want to add your translation